# How do I change date format in the submitted line using only template.php without node.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming

Using Drupal 8, I can change the date format, and adapt it to the country.

How can I do the same in a Drupal 7 site, where I do not want to create a node.tpl.php file in my theme since I need fast work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `template_preprocess_node` to alter `submitted` variable. Here is the sample code.

```
function awesome_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $date = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'm-d-Y - H:i');
  $variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['name'], '!datetime' => $date));
}
```

The most important line there is `$date = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'm-d-Y - H:i');`. Change the format (`m-d-Y - H:i`) to any format you want.

See [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) about PHP date format.

Comment: thank you! but really I did not check that my task may be solved with admin pages. In Configuration - Date and time I can add new Date format and then change Standard date format choosing my new one.

Comment: Yeah that is possible as well. But your question is using `template.php` and that why I provided this answer. Anyway glad you solved your problem in a less complicated manner.